# How to express a smoke interdiction in a classroom

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

The verb 피우다 is said to need a direct object complement. Therefore, it wouldn't be correct to say :
"교실에서 피울 수 없습니다."
in oder to express a smoke interdiction in a classroom.
Moreover the grammatically correct sentence :
"교실에서 담배를 피울 수 없습니다."
would express only the interdiction of the smoking of "담배" which means cigarette(s). So this sentence wouldn't forbide the smoking of calumets (peace pipes), narghiles, pipes, cigars, and so on.

Is there a korean verb meaning to smoke but not needing a direct object complement ?
Is there a sentence using 피우다 that would forbid the smoking of every source of smoke ?
How can be expressed a smoke interdiction in a classroom for all kinds of source of smoke ?

Comment: I believe typically "No Smoking" is just "금연" on signs.  Is your question other than this?

Comment: The thing is, we don't smoke anything other than cigs in Korea. So there is rarely the need to address anything other than 담배... As a result, when we do, we have no other option than 피우다.

Comment: @posh_pumpkin 그런데 어디서든지 바람은 피우면 안되는데...

Answer (score 4):

"No Smoking" is just "금연" on signs, and that will include all types of smoking (pipes and cigarettes).

[image]

If you need an entire sentence for a rule book:

> 교실에서는 금연 입니다

or as @posh_pumpkin points out:

> 교실은 금연구역 입니다

Comment: Alternatively, you can also say: 교실은 금연구역 입니다.

Comment: +1 찬성! (agreed)

Comment: What's the etimology of 금연구역 ?

Comment: @tripledragonvolant  hmm - you want to know the etimology, **"the origin of 금연구역 and the way in which the meanings of 금연구역 have changed throughout history**?  that sounds like a new question.